# Conditional formatting, select only visible cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code to select specific sheets and on button click email the data of all selected sheets. Now in one sheet there is conditional formatting applied on the dropdown list.

So the requirement is when dropdown option 1 is chosen, then below two cells are not visible. Secondly when dropdown option 2 is selected then all cells are visible.

With my code everything gets selected.

I tried this code :

```
overallrange = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:D50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Can someone advice better ways to do this....

Comment: Let's back up a step.  Why do you need to select any cells to begin with?  In most applications using VBA and Excel there is absolutely no reason to select anything (and often makes your life more complicated).  Try explaining what you are actually trying to do with the cells you are selecting and there might be a better way.

Comment: The actual scenario is I am building a macro for managers. They will fill the project requirement and the selected sheets containing data will at one go will be emailed to the solutions team.

Comment: Specify what you're intending to have done. It may be better to apply the formatting to everything and have the hide criteria in the *Formula1* property of the conditional formatting. This way if the data changes, the set of instructions will fire again without any macro being run. If you want your colors to stay static until the next macro runs or being changed manually, you may run the set of instructions with something along the lines of "For Each rng In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:D50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)". You can still be right with your ways but it looks wrong to us.

Answer (score -1):

You're headed the right way, see my sniplet below:

```
Sub ert()

Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:D50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.Select
    With Selection
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=TRUE" 'replace with your formula
        .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 49407 'give it a touch of orange
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

P.S. Noone tell him, gotta love the 1st of April. Will come back tomorrow.
Edit, back with more heat: let me highlight the **.Select** method emulates you selecting a *range* then the **Selection.** refers to the *range* selected. The *Select* in your code wastes resource and can cause errors (e.g. something cannot be selected so the *macro halts*, a selectionchange event *triggers* etc.) and looks *lousy*. For the above reasons (esp. lousiness) you don't select, you just define the range and then run the script for given range. This way you can save seconds of runtime while looking cool. The snipplet below is the cool variation of your sub-sub.

```
Sub ert()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("C1:D50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=TRUE" 'replace with your formula
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 49407 'give it a touch of orange
    End With
End Sub
```